# Async call to third party slows down a request

Tags: c#, .net, performance, rest, asynchronous

I have a command in .NET that creates some entities and returns a result. During the command, it sends an email with the information about the entity. It uses a service I get using DI and the call is async. I see when testing that sending this email can make the request take twice as long. The code is something like this.

```
public Guid CreateInvoice(string email, string name, ...)
{
    var transaction = await _context.Databse.BeginTransactionAsync();

    try {
       await _context.Invoice.AddAsync(new Invoice(email, name));
       // Some other CRUD operations here
    
       await _emailService.SendEmail(email, name); // This here adds the latency

       // Some other CRUD
       transaction.Commit();
       return newInvoice.Id;
    } 
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      transaction.Rollback();
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the `await` from the call of the email method. This obviously makes the code faster, but then I don't know if the method was send, which means that I cannot rollback the transaction if there is a problem. I want to rollback all of the CRUD if the method is not sent.

What is the best approach here? Should I add some retry policy for the sending so I don't have to worry about rolling back. Should I add some method in the email service that notifies the user that there was an error if the method fails? I can maybe split them and then call the email sending in the background so it is on its own. I am open to any ideas on how to tackle it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Email servers can sometimes be slow to respond, so queuing up an email to be sent and then having some background worker send the email would be best, but then you're back to the problem that you can't roll back the transaction if it fails. Are you sure you want a failed email to rollback the transaction?

Comment: The business logic is that when the user creates an invoice, they expect the email to be send, I think the best way to do it is show a status of the email in the client app, so the user can see if the email sending failed. Will it be enough to just omit the await, or should I run some background worker somehow to send the email?

Comment: What you can do is have "Didn't receive? resend " button. Almost all of the applications I have used use this kind of approach.

Comment: Just so that I understand the business logic. What happens when the email server is down which is possible? Does that mean all the invoices don't get created because the transaction commit is dependent on two actions - create and email? I think there might be room to reconsider how to approach this because creating an invoice can certainly be one function and the email can be another unless you absolutely must have the two dependent on each other.

Comment: Currently, if the email server is down, the invoices are not beign sent. I will go with the approach where I run the email sending in the background and then update the status of the invoice when it gets sent. Then I will just allow the user to see and possibly resent in case of failure. Thank you for the feedback! Can you please point me to a link where I can see how to run such a process in .NET Core API? Right now I have a single background process and it happens with a cron job that is directly executed so it is not the best approach

Comment: This look like a perfect candidate for the "Outbox pattern". If you think it is worth the additional time I would recommend you to look at his one: https://mbarkt3sto.hashnode.dev/microservices-architecture-the-outbox-pattern

Comment: It's generally not recommended to hold a transaction open so long anyway. Instead you need a brackground service which pulls off a queue (or from the database) and sends those emails.

Comment: You should never just "omit the await". You need to await any asynchronous calls you make, even if you don't immediately await them. Definitely need to make the email execution happen in the background and move it out of the transaction. There's lots of ways to do this. You can do it [directly in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services). Or publish to some sort of queue (database table, Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ etc) and have some other app be responsible for checking the queue and processing queue items.

Comment: Queues are essential for building scalable and performant apps. You might have a look at [MassTransit](https://masstransit.io/introduction) which is a set of .NET libraries for transparently working with different bus/queuing services such as Azure Service Bus, RabbitMQ, and Amazon SQS. Other options are available too, so do a bit of research to find what suits you best. The important part is figuring out the pattern.

Comment: @mason Sorry if that is a dumb question, but what if I just run the email sending code in the background? If I implement a queue, will that help by making sure that the sending doesn't fail (some type of retry policy)? Or it will make it so the threads are not overloaded if there are a lot of processes at once? I am just not sure if I need to implement a queue for such a case. While we are at it, will implement an "Outbox patter" count as having a queue, or I should look in some event bus specific approach? Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: You can run it in the background without a queue. But how do you propose to implement it without a queue? There's certainly ways to do it, but a queue is straightforward way of doing so. The outbox pattern that vhr mentioned is to write the event (the need to send an email) to a DB table, then have something publish that event to a message bus (the structure in that message bus would likely be a queue). In essence, that's creating two queues. The DB table, then the queue in the message broker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your business logic require the email to be sent within the transaction before the object gets saved to the database? I can't think of any reason for that to be a requirement. So, simply send the email after you commit the transaction. Then, you know for sure that your transaction has succeeded without worrying about a rollback.

Most email sending functionality doesn't need to be synchronous. This means you don't have to wait for the email to be sent successfully before continuing. Instead, delegate the email sending function to a background job. Then, implement a mechanism to update the status when the email has been sent.

Comment: The business logic requires that the customer knows if the email failed to send. Your suggestion will fit it because I will be able to track the status of the email and allow the user to resend it if it failed. Thanks for the feeback!